# New, delete, malloc, free

Tags: c++

`new` and `delete` are said to be preprocessors while `malloc` and `free` are functions. What is meant by `new` and `delete` being preprocessors?

Comment: New and delete are not "preprocessors". They have nothing to do with *the* preprocessor. New and delete are language directives. More precisely, they are unary operators like '+' and '*'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*new* and *delete* are C++ **operators** (like +, (), etc.) whereas *malloc* and *free* are (C) functions. Some operators (including new and delete) can be overloaded.