# C++: is malloc equivalent to new?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is the difference between new/delete and malloc/free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free)

I am a  noob in c++, want to know whether

```
memblock = (char *)malloc( currentByteLength);
```

is equivalent to

```
memblock = new char[currentByteLength]
```

in c++?

Comment: Have you tried them both?  Have you observed any differences?

Comment: I am trying to use this in alchemy and i find that the ordering is completely different. So what is the equivalent of memblock = new char[currentByteLength]

Comment: @abelenky: That's never a good way to discover how the language works.  You need to read the docs.  Case in point:  In this specific example, the behavior will not be observable different.  Nevertheless, `malloc` and `new` are very much not the same!

Comment: [Duplicate1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free), [duplicate2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new), [duplicate3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983182/new-delete-malloc-free), [duplicate4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807939/what-is-the-difference-between-new-and-malloc-and-calloc-in-c). Come on, guys, please search before asking questions.

Comment: @Øystein maybe a warning should show up whenever malloc and new are mentioned in the question :)

Comment: @karthick - beware here, most SO people don't actually understand this issue too well.  For instance, the first sentence of the top voted answer is just plain incorrect.  Both versions do not allocate on the heap.  The free-store (what new allocates from) MAY be implemented with the heap but doesn't have to be.  See my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
memblock = (char *)malloc( currentByteLength); 

memblock = new char[currentByteLength];
```

No difference now. But if you replace `char` with `int`, then yes, there would be difference, because in that case, `malloc` would allocate memory of size `currentByteLength`, while `new` would allocate memory of size `size(int) * currentByteLength`. So be very very careful.

Also, if the *type* you mention in `new` expression, is user-defined type, then the *default* constructor would be called `currentByteLength` number of times, to construct the objects!

For built-in types, there is no constructor!

Comment: Correct, that would require malloc * sizeof(int). But you're missing the point, the real difference is the constructor/destructor call.

Comment: @Quandary: I added that also. In fact I was adding that when you're writing that comment!

Comment: Why was this downvoted? what he said is correct.

Comment: seems that someone downvoted almost every answer here... not sure the point of that. hopefully they'll explain why.

Comment: @Downvoters : Can you please explain why you downvoted it? What exactly is wrong in it? Please point it out.

Comment: @Nawaz: I downvoted because `malloc` and `new[]` do not do the same thing as each other. `malloc` must be matched by `free`, and `new[]` must be matched by `delete[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Almost. I mean, both allocate data on the heap, and when dealing with primitive types such as char or int, it's about the same. There's an important difference, however, when dealing with objects. `new` invokes the object's constructor, while `malloc` doesn't. That's because `malloc` is a C function, and doesn't know anything about classes.

In general, `new` is the prefered way to dynamically allocate memory in C++, since it's typesafe and easier to use. Nothing prevents you from using `malloc`, but don't mix those up: do not call `delete` on memory allocated with `malloc`, or `free` on memory allocated with `new`. Bad things will happen otherwise. And do not use `delete` on an array created with `new[]`, or `delete[]` on an object created with `new` (yes, I know that's confusing, that's why you should use a `vector` instead).

Comment: what is the equivalent, in the C++ style, to `realloc`?

Comment: also: malloc always takes a free, whereas this new takes a delete[] and not a delete.

Comment: @Foo Bah There's none. You have to `new` another buffer and copy the original data in it, then release the original one. In any case, use a `vector`.

Comment: @wilhelmtell Woops, can't believe I forgot about that! Thanks!

Comment: also: if the two expressions yield the same amount of memory it's because they both ask for `char`. but change it to `int` and the two ask for two different sizes. (the first expression should have `currentByteLength*sizeof(T)` )

Comment: @Etienne there are use cases where malloc is preferred :)

Answer (score 3):

If the memory block is allocated with `malloc()`, you have to free it by calling `free()`. If it was allocated by means of `new[]`, you have to delete it by calling `delete []`. Using the wrong method of disposition is an error.

Also, new and malloc behave very differently when you allocate arrays of objects.

Also, they report out-of-memory condition differently - new throws an exception, malloc returns a zero.

Answer (score 2):

The `new` keyword allocates memory in the `free-store`.  The `malloc` function allocates memory in the `heap`.

Many implementations use the heap to implement the free-store, but they don't have to be related at all.  They can, and often do, have completely different managers.

As far as your code should be concerned, the memory blocks allocated by your particular examples could be considered equivalent.  This is a pretty corner case though and you still need to make sure you deallocate the block in the correct place (free-store vs. heap).  It's better if you just never consider them the same thing at all.

Here's a good tutorial on memory in C++: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/009.htm

Answer (score 1):

not exactly, malloc() is C function and new is C++ operator, also 
if your case their a both allocate buffer but if malloc() fails then is return NULL.
but if new fails is throw an exception.

for more info read [this session in C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  Yes, that is how you allocate memory dynamically in C++.

Long answer:  No, they are different beasts.  The most obvious difference is that memory that is `malloc()`'ed must be `free()`'ed, while memory that is `new`'ed must be `delete`d.

`new` calls the default constuctor of the type, is type-safe, throws an exception on error, and can be overridden.

In C++, you should always be using `new` over `malloc()`, unless you need to interface with code written in C.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

1. They have different spellings (duh :P)
2. They require different methods of freeing the memory (`malloc` / `free` vs. `operator new[]` / `operator delete[]`)
3. When they fail, they have different behaviors. `malloc` returns 0, `operator new[]` throws an exception.

This is only in your particular case though. There are even more differences when:

1. You are allocating non-POD objects (here, constructors & destructors get called)
2. The elements are non-char-sized (here, you need to do a bit of math for `malloc` -- this would illustrate how `operator new` is more intuitive for allocating *objects* instead of a *blob*)

I don't think this is a great question... what are you really asking? Difference in terms of what? No, you cannot interchange them blindly.

Comment: @above: so what is the equivalent of memblock = new char[currentBytelength]?

Answer (score 0):

It is roughly equivalent (exception/null and constructor aside) in the case that `char` is 1 byte in size, otherwise for the first one you should multiply by the data type size.

```
memblock = (char *)malloc( currentByteLength * sizeof(char) );
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is one by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
memblock = new DATATYPE[length]
```

is equivalent to

```
memblock = (DATATYPE*) malloc(length * sizeof(DATATYPE));
```

If and only if there is no constructor, and if and only if datatype is not a pointer itselfs.

Free and delete are equivalent only if there's no destructor.

If there's no constructor/destructor, you can call new/malloc delete/free interchangably and even with mixing.

new and delete create the memory for a new object calling the constructor/destructor (if available), while malloc and free just allocate the memory (without calling constructor/destructor).

Answer (score 0):

The main differences (specifically referring to char) are:

- How to actually clear the memory at the end [first uses free, second uses delete]
- Sizes may be different (if char is actually a wide 2-byte character, then the first allocates only enough space for currentByteLength bytes whereas the new allocates currentByteLength * 2 bytes)
- malloc will fail by returning null, but new will throw a runtime exception

FYI: should always put a sizeof check for the malloc:

```
memblock = (char *)malloc( sizeof(char) * currentByteLength);
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is one by definition.